# Collection structural type parameter weirdness

Tags: scala, generics, structural-typing

This seems like a simple thing but I can't understand it...

This compiles:

```
object CanFoo1 {
  def foo(): Unit = {
    println("Yup, I can foo alright")
  }
}

object CanFoo2 {
  def foo(): Unit = {
    println("And I can foo with the best")
  }
}

trait A {
  type CanFoo = { def foo(): Unit }
  def fooers: Seq[CanFoo]
}

class B extends A {
  def fooers = Seq(
    // CanFoo1, // <- won't compile when this is uncommented
    CanFoo2
  )
}
```

But uncommenting the `// CanFoo1,` line gives:

```
error: type mismatch;
found   : Seq[Object]
required: Seq[B.this.CanFoo]
   (which expands to)  Seq[AnyRef{def foo(): Unit}]
def fooers = Seq(
              ^
one error found
```

So it seems like the compiler understands that a collection containing just one element `Seq(CanFoo2)` (or `Seq(CanFoo1)`) is of the correct type, but when both objects are in the collection it gives up? What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So it seems like the compiler understands that a collection containing
>   just one element `Seq(CanFoo2)` (or `Seq(CanFoo1)`) is of the correct
>   type, but when both objects are in the collection it gives up? What am
>   I doing wrong here?

When you pass `CanFoo1` or `CanFoo2` to the `Seq` apply, the sequence is inferred to be of type `CanFoo1.type` or `CanFoo2.type` respectively, it is not inferred to be of type `CanFoo`.

When you pass in both elements to the `Seq`, the compiler tries to look for a common type to which it can validly infer to make the code compile, and the only type it can find is `Object`, but `fooers` is said to be of type `Seq[CanFoo]`, so the compiler yells.

You can help the compiler a little by explicitly writing the type of the collection:

```
class B extends A {
  def fooers = Seq[CanFoo](
    CanFoo1,
    CanFoo2
  )
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick & informative answer. I think I understand now - without an explicit type parameter the Collection type is inferred from the elements, and -then- this inferred type is checked for conformation to the structural type. The type inferencer does not include the declared structural type in the things it knows about when deducing the type of the Seq.